# give alt-text of image a style

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using the `alt` attribute of an `<image>` to read it and display in a `<div>`

```
 <img src="charlotte/1_verwandelbar.jpg" alt="Some text in here" />
 <div class="text_slider"></div>
```

and in a callback function of `cycle.js`, using property `this.alt` I get the `alt` text and append it into a `<p>` tag.

```
$('.text_slider').html('<p style="color: #fff;">' + $(this).attr('alt') + '<p>');
```

My problem is, that I can't make any `<br>` in the `alt`, which means something like `alt="text here <br> text more"`

Has anyone have a solution?

**Edit: My Code works very well, the mistake was an error elsewhere in my code.**

Comment: Do you mean you want a way to put newlines into your alt text?

Comment: What problem are you having? It works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/t3GC5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<br>` works fine for me (tested in chrome and firefox). Could you explain what's not working?

```
<html>
<head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="pep" src="/home/tapia/varios/tag.png" alt="Some text <br>in here" />
    <div class="text_slider"></div>
    <script>
        $('img').one('load', function() {
            $('.text_slider').html('<p style="color: #f00;">' + $(this).attr('alt') + '<p>');
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: okay got the problem, its important to have no spaces between. eg `alt="hello my name <br> is blabla` has to be `alt="hello my name<br>is blabla`

Comment: nope, i tried it three times, and everytime i have spaces in it it does not break!

Comment: Could you please paste your code? You probably have an error somewhere else, an extra space shouldn't make it any different.

Comment: Although it works you probably don;t want a <br> tag in your alt text, because of the SEO friendliness of your site.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a random character in your alt text and then replace it?

For example a middot: `&middot`;
and then replace it when you show the `p` tag

```
$('.text_slider').html('<p style="color: #fff;">' + $(this).attr('alt').replace("&middot;", "<br>") + '<p>');
```